# How to check is PowerShell action has ended

Tags: powershell

I need to run a `PowerShell` like this:

```
Connect-SomeServer localhost;
Import-SomeTemplate C:\temp\info.zip
```

This action opens a progress bar in `PowerShell ISE`. Sometimes the action can pass after 30 seconds, and sometimes it can take 7 minutes or even more.

How can I check that the progress bar (action) has ended?

Comment: Maybe you can check Windows Task Manager for the process?

Comment: You need to run the code asynchronously to be able to check status.  You current code blocks until the code completes.  So you need to run the code as function and run function async.  See : https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-async/#:~:text=The%20most%20frequent%20kind%20of,that%20function's%20execution%20is%20complete.